# Login to a site with Requests-html

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I am trying to login to a site through Python as if I am going to scrape it, but after trying for several hours I could not figure out why after I receive authorization token through successful post request I still receive a get html response as if I am not logged in.
The website is https://www.packtpub.com/ and below is my code.

```
import requests_html
import json

s_async = requests_html.AsyncHTMLSession()

#define vars for post request

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.41 Safari/537.36 Edg/101.0.1210.32"
data = {"username":username,"password":password}
post_url = "https://services.packtpub.com/auth-v1/users/tokens"
headers = {"User-Agent":user_agent}

#post request
r_post = await s_async.post(post_url,json=data,headers=headers)

if r_post.status_code!=200:
    raise Exception("Check response code from post request")

#define vars for get request's header

#auth_token has the 'Bearer ' prefix added as this is how the authorization
#token is sent in the get header by my browser inspected through DevTools

auth_token = 'Bearer '+json.loads(r_post.text)['data']['access']
accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*"
accept_encoding = "gzip, deflate, br"
accept_language = "en-US,en;q=0.9,bg;q=0.8"
origin = "https://account.packtpub.com"
referer = "https://account.packtpub.com/"
#sec_ch_ua= r" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Microsoft Edge";v="101"
sec_ch_ua_mobile = "?0"
sec_ch_ua_platform = "Windows"
##sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec_fetch_mode = "cors"
sec_fetch_site = "same-site"

#the detailed headers are an attempt to copy get header from the successful get request by the browser
headers = {"User-Agent":user_agent, 
       "authorization":auth_token,
      "accept":accept,
      "accept-encoding":accept_encoding,
       "accept-language":accept_language,
      "origin":origin,
      "referer":referer,
      "sec-ch-ua-mobile":sec_ch_ua_mobile,
      "sec-ch-ua-platform":sec_ch_ua_platform,
      "sec-fetch-mode":sec_fetch_mode,
      "sec-fetch-site":sec_fetch_site}

#get request
r_get = await s_async.get("https://www.packtpub.com",headers=headers)


if r_get.status_code!=200:
    raise Exception("Check response code from get request")

await r_get.html.arender()

#looking for signs that the login is successful, more specifically I am looking for
#the absence of the "User Sign In" button

with open(r"C:\packtpub_inspect.html","wb") as file:
    file.write(r_get.html.raw_html)`
```